# Extracting a value from a string using sed

Tags: sed, tcsh

I have the following code:

```
set MARKER_LIST = "t14_noTap_leftSlow t24_noTap_leftMedium t34_noTap_leftFast \
 t44_noTap_rightSlow t54_noTap_rightMedium t64_noTap_rightFast \
 t74_noTap_inphaseSlow t84_noTap_inphaseMedium t94_noTap_inphaseFast \
 t104_noTap_antiphaseSlow t114_noTap_antiphaseMedium t124_noTap_antiphaseFast"

foreach code (${MARKER_LIST})

set evt_code = `echo ${code} | sed 's/^.*t[0-9]*_noTap_//'`
echo "Extracted value: $evt_code"
end
```

I'm trying to extract the string after "tXX_noTap_" and "tXXX_noTap_" but it doesn't seem to be working. Would appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Just in case you don't know - [don't write scripts in \[t\]csh](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not). In particular see http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ and https://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not declare `tcsh` as the shell to interpret the script. So `sh`-aware code is expected.
Start your script with the correct shebang in the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
```

---

*Just beyond your question:*

1. Your  `sed` code itself is fine, but *perhaps* unnecessary complicated:

   ```
   sed 's/^.*_//'
   ```

   should be enough, except you expect output with `_` in the desired part of the string.
2. Please eliminate all the `\` with their line breaks in `${MARKER_LIST}`. Else the result will contain empty values at each appearance of `\`:

   ```
   Extracted value: leftSlow
   Extracted value: leftMedium
   Extracted value: leftFast
   Extracted value: 
   Extracted value: rightSlow
   Extracted value: rightMedium
   Extracted value: rightFast
   Extracted value: 
   Extracted value: inphaseSlow
   Extracted value: inphaseMedium
   Extracted value: inphaseFast
   Extracted value: 
   Extracted value: antiphaseSlow
   Extracted value: antiphaseMedium
   Extracted value: antiphaseFast
   ```

So this would be your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

set MARKER_LIST = "t14_noTap_leftSlow t24_noTap_leftMedium t34_noTap_leftFast t44_noTap_rightSlow   t54_noTap_rightMedium t64_noTap_rightFast t74_noTap_inphaseSlow t84_noTap_inphaseMedium t94_noTap_inphaseFast t104_noTap_antiphaseSlow t114_noTap_antiphaseMedium t124_noTap_antiphaseFast"

foreach code (${MARKER_LIST})
    set evt_code = `echo ${code} | sed 's/^.*t[0-9]*_noTap_//'`
    echo "Extracted value: $evt_code"
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Both answers worked well, but chose this one as the accepted answer simply because of the simplified sed command (I'll be able to apply for a few of my other files that don't follow the same format but do have an underscore I will use as my separator).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you were almost there

use the "`g`" option at the end of the sed statement to replace all occurences.
And you don't want to prefix the regex with `^.*` if you want to replace every occurence starting with `tXX_noTap_`

```
echo "t14_noTap_leftSlow t24_noTap_leftMedium t34_noTap_leftFast \
       t44_noTap_rightSlow t54_noTap_rightMedium t64_noTap_rightFast \
       t74_noTap_inphaseSlow t84_noTap_inphaseMedium t94_noTap_inphaseFast \
       t104_noTap_antiphaseSlow t114_noTap_antiphaseMedium t124_noTap_antiphaseFast" \
    | sed 's/t[0-9]*_noTap_//g'
```

Comment: You can simplify even further with '`s/^.*noTap_//g'`. Good luck to all.